# Attempt to index global 'LM' (a nil value)

Tags: lua, null, lua-table

I am working on a some code in Lua and I keep getting this error although it is defined.

It is saying that 'LM' is a nil value when it's clearly not as `LM = {}` is the first thing I have in my code. I am using that table for functions.

```
LM = {}
LM.Classes = {}
LM.Factions = {}
LM.Items = {}
LM.Core = {}
LM.Ent = {}
LM.GUI = {}
LM.Core.ValidLMEntities = {
                "fm_item",
                "fm_keys",
                "fm_fists",
                "fm_money",
                }

function LM.Core.IsLMEntity(ent)    
    return IsValid(ent) && table.HasValue(LM.Core.ValidLMEntities, ent:GetClass())
end
```

Error message:

```
[ERROR]
gamemodes/lemonmuffin/gamemode/sv_core.lua:1: attempt to index global 'LM' (a nil value) 
  1. unknown - gamemodes/lemonmuffin/gamemode/sv_core.lua:1
  2. include - [C]:-1 
  3. unknown - gamemodes/lemonmuffin/gamemode/init.lua:1
```

Comment: can't help you if you don't show us the code. Are we suppose to guess?

Comment: what's the error callstack?

Comment: `&&` isn't valid lua syntax, did you mean `and`?

Comment: [ERROR] gamemodes/lemonmuffin/gamemode/sv_core.lua:1: attempt to index global 'LM' (a nil value)
 1. unknown - gamemodes/lemonmuffin/gamemode/sv_core.lua:1
  2. include - [C]:-1
   3. unknown - gamemodes/lemonmuffin/gamemode/init.lua:1

Comment: && is exactly the same as 'and'

Comment: How can I fix this? Anyone?

Comment: Is the the code snippet shown part of `sv_core.lua`? More context is needed.

Comment: Yes it's part of sv_core.lua

Comment: The error is in line 1 of `sv_core.lua` and the error says Lua tries to index it. There is no indexing operation in line 1 of the snippet you gave us though. Clearly you are not telling us everything we would need to know to offer you a solution

Answer (score 4):

Take care, you've used `&&` which is *not* the same as `and`.
Here's the full list of all Lua non-word tokens (there's no `&`):

```
 +     -     *     /     %     ^     #
 ==    ~=    <=    >=    <     >     =
 (     )     {     }     [     ]     ::
 ;     :     ,     .     ..    ...
```

*see [Reference Manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html) for more details.*

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
LM = {Classes,Factions,Items,Core,Ent,GUI}
LM.Classes = {}
LM.Factions = {}
LM.Items = {}
LM.Core = {}
LM.Ent = {}
LM.GUI = {}

LM.Core.ValidLMEntities = {
            "fm_item",
            "fm_keys",
            "fm_fists",
            "fm_money",
            }

function LM.Core.IsLMEntity(ent)    
     return IsValid(ent) and table.HasValue(LM.Core.ValidLMEntities, ent:GetClass())
end
```